# Android better approach to wait service creation

Tags: android

I am facing one issue:

My login task takes awhile in the first run... around 30-60 seconds...

This is a performance problem i can't solve now, so i'm trying to deal the best way... since 90% of the users wont wait 60 seconds looking to the screen watching the progress bar load i made the `login` a method of my service, which runs in background so user can go to any other app and still be fine.

The service is created during `Application` `onCreate` and this procedure works fine...

THE PROBLEM:

In order to save user time, after first successful login i cache some auth data, and when the user next uses the app the login form is already filled, so if he goes very fast and click on login, android system didn't create MyService yet and the call `MyService.login(params)` throws nullpointer

Since i can't control the order android creates the activities/services during application `oncreate` is there a better approach to this problem than simple put a loop with a new thread waiting to the service be ready?

==========UPDATE==========

just to let things clear

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication{

    //many stuff

    public void onCreate(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(intent);
        //many other stuff
    }
}

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //try to recover auth data from cache
        Auth a = getCachedAuth();
        if(a !=null)
            MyService.getInstance().login(a);

        //else wait for user input auth data
    }
}
```

`MyService.getInstance()` will be `null` until the android system has instantiated it from the intent i gave...

But as i said, i've no control over the order android decide to run its tasks... so, sometimes the service is instantiated first, sometimes the activity is... how to deal?

Comment: If the user can click the the login button, that means onCreate already finished. I'm not sure the problem is what you think.

Comment: @UdiIdan, see my update please

Comment: If the issue is that startService does the work asynchronously, rather than a loop to check for the service (poling) you can setup some sort of listener/callback for the result of starting the service (edge trigger) that starts or unblocks Login in the activity.  
  


You can depend on the App:onCreate to be ["Called when the application is starting, before any activity, service, or receiver objects (excluding content providers) have been created."][1]  So before the LoginActivity:onCreate.


  [1]: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application#onCreate()]